# How to add app links to the right click menu

Tags: 14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.
When I right click the desktop and select "New Document" the only option is "Empty Document". I want to add to that list other apps but do not remember where that folder is located.
Example: I want to right click the desktop and be able to open a gnumeric file.

If more info is need, please let me know.
Trolls, do not bother responding.
Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score -1):

The default name for that folder is `$HOME/Templates` in your user's home folder (e.g. `/home/ray/Templates/`).

If you are using a non-English environment the folder name may be translated. See the file `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, there should be a line like

```
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Vorlagen"
```

telling you the folder name. In this case it's `$HOME/Vorlagen`.

Create that folder if it doesn't exist and put a Gnumeric file in.